# How can I store the photo even after I close the app and start it again?

Tags: android

I am trying to build a project, where the user can take a photo from his phone or he can choose from his gallery. This is working good but whenever I am closing the app and start it again the photo is getting disappeared. 
How can I store the photo even after I close the app and start it again?
Here is the code I've done so far.

```
Button igallery;
Button icamera;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
private static final int TAKE_IMAGE = 1;
private Bitmap bImageBitmap;
private String sCurrentPhotoPath;
private ImageView imageview;
igallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iGallary);
icamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iCamera);
imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);     

private void openCamera() {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_IMAGE);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageview.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

    else if (requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        /*FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);*/

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Umm, how does the question in your body have anything to do with the question in your topic?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it. I copied the codes from editor but forgot to change the title which is from previous question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Save url to SharedPreferences and load it after device rotation. Yor problem seems not related to question name. In Java only single base class is allowed, but you can implement as many interfaces as you want. It is good, because mixed up base class can be stored as a reference - use composition  instead of inheritance.

Comment: If you kindly elaborate a little it would help me a lot.